# How to pass different value when switchMap is not executed? Android + Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have a huge understanding problem here, I have a ecommerce app and I cannot properly calculate value of users cart.
The problem is, my solution works well to the point but I have an issue when there are no products in the cart. Obviously LiveData observer or switchMap will not get executed when it's value is empty.

It seems like something trivial, only thing I want to do here is handle the situation when user have no products in the cart. Is the livedata and switchMap a wrong approach here?

I get userCart from the repo -> I calculate its value in the viewModel and expose it to the view with dataBinding.

```
@HiltViewModel
class CartFragmentViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
    private val repository: ProductRepository,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val priceFormatter: PriceFormatter
) : ViewModel() {

    private val user = userRepository.currentUser

    val userCart = user.switchMap {
        repository.getProductsFromCart(it.cart)
    }

    val cartValue = userCart.switchMap {
        calculateCartValue(it)
    }

    private fun calculateCartValue(list: List<Product>?): LiveData<String> {

        val cartVal = MutableLiveData<String>()
        var cartValue = 0L

        list?.let { prods ->
            prods.forEach {
                cartValue += it.price
            }
            cartVal.postValue(priceFormatter.formatPrice(cartValue))
        } ?: cartVal.postValue(priceFormatter.formatPrice(0))

        return cartVal
    }

    fun removeFromCart(product: Product) {
        userRepository.removeFromCart(product)
        getUserData()
    }

    private fun getUserData() {
        userRepository.getUserData()
    }

    init {
        getUserData()
    }
}
```

Comment: A common approach is to have an `EMPTY_CART` object that triggers the whole thing, but contains the default/empty value.

Comment: Thank you this is a fair suggestion but the main problem is I have no clue how to trigger cartValue to be changed when users removes products from the cart. If user opens cart and its empty then fine, but I struggle to display 0.00 when users removes products as after removal of final product cart is empty and observer or variable with switchMap will not get updated at all.

Comment: Yeah, observeForever is fine :) I think [this is better](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow) but also "experimental" (I think) :) The thing is, your ViewModel may survive longer than what you want, and during that period, you will be "wasting resourceS" by observing something you don't care. Take a look (but I would only consider those *after* you have gotten your new architecture working) :)

Comment: Been reading about flows already, this app will be done bit differently though.
Thanks man, I have small hiccups still and I think Ill make a reusable interface for exposing state to make it cleaner throughout the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value is to solve the "initial" empty cart.

Now if you need to trigger it when there's no data... (aka: after you remove items and the list is now empty), I'd use a `sealed class` to wrap the actual value.

(names and code are pseudo-code, so please don't copy-paste)

Something like this:

- Your Repository should expose the cart, user, etc. wrapped in a sealed class:

```
sealed class UserCartState {
   object Empty : UserCartState()
   data class HasItems(items: List<things>)
   object Error(t: Throwable) :UserCartState() //hypotetical state to signal problems
}
```

- In your `CartFragmentViewModel`, you observe and use `when` (for example), to determine what did the repo responded with.

```
repo.cartState.observe(...) {
   when (state)  { 
     is Empty -> //deal with it
     is HasItems -> // do what it takes to convert it, calculate it, etc.
     is Error -> // handle it
   }
}
```

- When the user removes the last item in the cart, your repo should emit `Empty`.
- The VM doesn't care how that happened, it simply reacts to the new state.
- The UI cares even less. :)

You get the idea (I hope).

That's how I would look into it.

You can even use a `flow` of cart items, or the new "FlowState" thingy (see the latest Google I/O 21) to conserve resources when the lifecycle owner is not ready.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I really am. 
It works like a charm and the whole topic of exposing states is inspiring. I have been using a similar approach to handle states of data processing though the api requests(Resource class) so I knew what you are talking about. 
Now I need to refactor the code and finally move on :) 

You are advising to use observer in ViewModel, why? It is an anti-pattern in general afaik. I am using observeForever and removing observer in onCleared() and it seems to be fine but I need to dig deeper in performance of this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this part of code creates the problem

```
list?.let { prods ->
        prods.forEach {
            cartValue += it.price
        }
        cartVal.postValue(priceFormatter.formatPrice(cartValue))
    } ?: cartVal.postValue(priceFormatter.formatPrice(0))
```

Probably, list is not null but is empty. Please try this:

```
    if (list.isNullOrEmpty) {
        list.forEach {
            cartValue += it.price
        }
        cartVal.postValue(priceFormatter.formatPrice(cartValue))
    } else {
        cartVal.postValue(priceFormatter.formatPrice(0))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is different, when I remove all products from cart switchMap cannot be executed so the code is not running anyways and I am looking for a proper(not a workaround) way to fix that, how would a production ready app have this handled. But solution from Martin is outstanding!

Comment: Ok then, proceed with his solution!